# Invoke stored procedure from another thread not working c#, EntityFramework

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure to clean up some data.

When I invoke from Program.cs like following its not working

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      LogCleaner logCleaner = new LogCleaner(appConfiguration);
      Task.Run(() => logCleaner.Start());
    }
```

LogCleaner.Start function as following

```
        try
        {
            using(UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(this.appConfiguration.DefaultConnectionString))
            {
                var result = unitOfWork.E3DLogs.CleanUpLogs(this.appConfiguration.CleanUpDayCount);
                logger.Info("Clean up stored procedure executed, Result: " + result.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("Error while cleaning the log messages. Error Message: " + e.Message);
        }
```

unitOfWork.E3DLogs.CleanUpLogs as following

```
    public int CleanUpLogs(int dayCount)
    {
        return _E3DDbcontext.CleanUpLogs(dayCount);
    }
```

_E3DDbcontext.CleanUpLogs function as following

```
    public virtual int CleanUpLogs(Nullable<int> dayCount)
    {
        var dayCountParameter = dayCount.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("dayCount", dayCount) :
            new ObjectParameter("dayCount", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("CleanUpLogs", dayCountParameter);
    }
```

When I invoke from Program.cs like following its working

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      LogCleaner logCleaner = new LogCleaner(appConfiguration);
      logCleaner.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You are never awaiting the task you created in task.run(). Could It be that the programm exits faster than the task can execute?

Comment: Please define "its not working" - what actually *happens*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A process (exe) exits when the last non-background thread terminates, which *for simple applications* means: when `Main` exits. The thread-pool that services `Task.Run` uses *background* threads, so they don't count in terms of application lifetime.

Running the code directly prevents this. Alternatively, you could do (if relevant):

```cs
static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    LogCleaner logCleaner = new LogCleaner(appConfiguration);
    var logCleaner = Task.Run(() => logCleaner.Start());

    // presumably some other code to run here, because if there wasn't:
    // you'd just run logCleaner.Start() directly

    return logCleaner; // include the log-cleaner in the application lifetime
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do `await logCleaner;` and make `Main` async

Comment: @Charlieface if you had other async things to do in `Main`, then that would make sense; there's no need to `await` it otherwise, though - can just return it and let the caller worry about that